# GWT 2.4 app can't find my CSS file whose classes are being used in code via UIObject.addStyleName

Tags: java, css, gwt, gwt2

How does GWT look for an CSS file whose classes are being used in code via UIObject.addStyleName() ? What should I do to make my control find my css ?

I have relatively big project. I created my own [editor](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors) which I create completely programmatically without adjacent UiBinder xml.

I assign css style to certain internal ui objects of my editor via calls to [UIObject.addStyleName()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html).

I can't understand where I should place my CSS so that GWT would find it in run-time.

I tried:

- Placing required css classes into CSS file that is referenced in UiBinder template of a form that uses my editor using "ui:style" tag.
- Creating separate css file in client\ folder and referencing it in gwt module xml using "stylesheet" tag.

None of these methods worked.

Answer (score 2):

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss#cssfiles

There are 4 ways (that I'd split in 2 categories) to get CSS in your app:

- an external stylesheet: reference it from your `gwt.xml` or from your HTML host page. To bundle it in your app, either put it in a `public` folder within your module (next to your `client` package); or in your *war* folder. Have a look at the themes bundled in GWT to see this in effect.
- a `CssResource`: put the CSS file in your `client` hierarchy along with `ClientBundle` and `CssResource` interfaces. `ui:style` in UiBinder works the same, as it dynamically generates a `CssResource`, using the attributes of the `ui:style` as annotations to the method in the `ClientBundle`, and the content of the `ui:style` as a dynamically generated CSS file (referenced *via* the `@Source` annotation). UiBinder also automatically calls `ensureInjected()` for you, as you don't necessarily have a handle on the generated `CssResource`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using:

```
YOURSTYLENAMECLASS().ensureInjected();
```

before adding it to your element.

here is the JavaDoc for `ensureInjected()`, which explains it better than my own words ;):

```
package com.google.gwt.resources.client;
//....
public interface CssResource extends CssResourceBase {
//...

* Calls
* {@link com.google.gwt.dom.client.StyleInjector#injectStylesheet(String)} to
* inject the contents of the CssResource into the DOM. Repeated calls to this
* method on an instance of a CssResources will have no effect.
* 
* @return <code>true</code> if this method mutated the DOM.
*/
boolean ensureInjected();
```